# Bootstrap 4 - row not responsive on mobile

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div class="row table-row">
      <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-5.jpg" class="rounded-circle z-depth-0" alt="avatar image" height="35" />
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5">Felecia Burke</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 d-none d-sm-block">Staff</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 d-none d-sm-block">+1 (070) 123-4567</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4">example@mail.com</div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h table-row-menu"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Simple question, grid works on all other devices, but on mobile it's not even showing media queries. Very strange and I would appreciate another pair of eyes to take a look at this.

I want all divs to be visible of tablet, laptop or larger devices, but on mobile I want to hide Staff and phone number.

It displays everything in block style on mobile, I don't know why.

Template is copied from Bootstrap's official site.

Comment: It is working fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is it not hitting the xs screen size maybe? Is there a min-width on anything. I would try .d-sm-none .d-md-block and see if that works for the screen size you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just throwing this out to show you, and then I can erase it. Everything is working as you say, the Mobile View staff and phone number are lost. Where is the problem ?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  <div class="row table-row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-5.jpg" class="rounded-circle z-depth-0" alt="avatar image" height="35" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5">Felecia Burke</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 d-none d-sm-block">Staff</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 d-none d-sm-block">+1 (070) 123-4567</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4">example@mail.com</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
      <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h table-row-menu"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```